# howto launch my application like MS-Office applications do using automation

Tags: c#

I am writing a c# application which references a separate dll which contains all the automation features i am trying to implement such as Application Object Model, doing all this by using delegates and events.

What i want to be able todo is to reference my dll containing the application object model in a different process and for it to automatically launch my application, like MS-Word does when you call its application.

Example:

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

Word object model loads in the WinWord.exe running its own process how can i achieve this as well.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

What you need is an out-of-process COM automation server.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756541/creating-a-com-automation-server-in-c) question has a number of replies that should give you some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

The way that Word does it is that it's an out of process executable COM Server. You can write your own out of process COM servers.

Here's some information about COM Servers:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OLE_Automation#Object_models_for_specific_applications

And here's a question discussing how to do this in C#:
[Creating a COM Automation Server in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756541/creating-a-com-automation-server-in-c)